# How to create two columns with two entirely separate texts in each, side-by-side?

Tags: two-column

Newb here. When I look up how to create two columns, I get a bunch of tutorials that assume one text will run from the bottom of column A to the top of column B, like a newspaper article that spans two columns.

That's not what I want to do. I want to put one text in the left column, a different text in the right column. Like two separate newspaper columns.

When the text reaches the bottom of column A, instead of picking up at the top of column B, it should start at the top of column A on the next page.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some like this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{geometry}
\usepackage{paracol}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usepackage{parskip}
\begin{document}
\lipsum[1]
\begin{paracol}{2}
\color{blue} 
\lipsum[2-20]
\switchcolumn
\color{red}
\lipsum[22-40]
\end{paracol}
\lipsum[41]
\end{document}
```

[image: mwe]